# When saving an entity in EF Core, using only an ID for a navigational property returns null for that property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework Core 3, I'm trying to save an entity. Because I don't want to retrieve the linked object of the User field when I already know the Id, I'm only setting the ID field of that property.

This is (a stripped down version of) my entity:

```
[Table("Samples")]
public class Sample
{
    public Sample() { }
    
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public uint Id { get; set; }

    public uint CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

I have UseLazyLoadingProxies() enabled and this works with other entities.

Now, because I already know the ID and don't want to do a DB round trip, I create a new sample like this and use the UserId of 1:

```
var sample = new Sample
{
    CreatedBy = 1
};

var result = await this._context.Samples.AddAsync(sample);
await this._context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Now inside result.Entity, I find that CreatedByUser is null and not proxied, even though the relationship exists in the database and it is saved correctly. When I retrieve the entity separately, it does work.

Is there any way to retrieve get the correct object directly after saving the sample entity?

EDIT: As to add to the confusion. When I do this:

```
var user = await userService.GetUserByIdAsync(1);
    
var sample = new Sample(sampleRequest)
{
    CreatedByUser = user
};
```

It works. But when I revert this change to this:

```
var sample = new Sample
{
    CreatedBy = 1
};
```

It still works!!!

Looks like there is some sort of caching system going on.

EDIT2: Ok, it's not caching. Just calling
`await userService.GetUserByIdAsync(1);`
makes it work.

However, I don't want to make this extra call to the database, I expect SaveAllChanges() to also retrieve the User entity for me (without the Include).

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. You should treat retrieving the user as a separate operation.

Comment: Well, usually, navigational properties are lazy loaded without the need for a separate operation or Include.

Comment: Have you tried Attach? `_context.Attach(sample);`

Comment: @mxmissile Yes that works!! Thank you!

Comment: Could you add this as an answer so I can mark it at solution? :)

Comment: Looks like this was not the solution after all :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `Attach()`, this will attach the entity to the context and proxy your navigational properties:

`_context.Attach(sample);`

[More on Attach() here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-5.0).

Comment: Looks I was celebrating too early. I added your code and it worked. But the funny thing is, it now also works when I remove this code and by the looks of it, it was not the Attach that fixed it, but me adding and removing code to first load the full user entity and then assigning it.

So it looks there is a caching issue going on.

Comment: It should be done automatically without attach